# how to make two loops in code only one loop

Tags: python, loops

Hello everyone just I want to ask if I can make this code with only one loop, is it possible ??

```py
    import turtle
    turtle.bgcolor("white")
    turtle.pensize(2) 
    turtle.speed(0)

    m =turtle.Turtle()
    m.hideturtle()
    m.penup()
    m.goto(-350,50)
    m.showturtle()
    m.pendown()
    m.goto(5,5)
    for i in range(6):
        for colors in ["brown","red","magenta","blue","green","orange"]:
            turtle.color(colors)
            turtle.circle(100)
            turtle.right(10)
```

Comment: yea help me out, please. i am new in python try to do something I don't know

Comment: yea u can use 6 its all right

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this by multiplying the list holding your colors, since you don't use the i value anywhere the program will work the same:

```py
import turtle
turtle.bgcolor("white")
turtle.pensize(2) 
turtle.speed(0)

m =turtle.Turtle()
m.hideturtle()
m.penup()
m.goto(-350,50)
m.showturtle()
m.pendown()
m.goto(5,5)

for colors in ["brown","red","magenta","blue","green","orange"] * 36:
     turtle.color(colors)
     turtle.circle(100)
     turtle.right(10)
```

However, I don't think it's worth it because it will make your code less readable.

Comment: Glad to be of help. I would recommend reading about lists in python, there are a lot of "tricks" that make writing easy to read code very quick in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

You could repeat the code in your first loop for each colour, like this:

```
import turtle
turtle.bgcolor("white")
turtle.pensize(2) 
turtle.speed(0)

m =turtle.Turtle()
m.hideturtle()
m.penup()
m.goto(-350,50)
m.showturtle()
m.pendown()
m.goto(5,5)
for i in range(36):
    
    turtle.color("brown")
    turtle.circle(100)
    turtle.right(10)

    turtle.color("red")
    turtle.circle(100)
    turtle.right(10)

    turtle.color("magenta")
    turtle.circle(100)
    turtle.right(10)

    turtle.color("blue")
    turtle.circle(100)
    turtle.right(10)

    turtle.color("green")
    turtle.circle(100)
    turtle.right(10)

    turtle.color("orange")
    turtle.circle(100)
    turtle.right(10)
```

But I don't recommend doing that because it is inefficient, messy, and bad practice

Comment: with a modulo you can keep it DRY

Comment: ok got it but i can do it with both  ways